# Doctrine 2.0 - Problem while adding

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am using doctrine 2.0 and created entities based on schema.

I have two entities Messages and Users

and **userid** in messages is linked to **id** in users.

when i created entities i got something like this in messages entity

```
/**
 * Set from
 *
 * @param UserDetails $from
 */
public function setFrom(\UserDetails $from)
{
    $this->from = $from;
}
```

how can i set the from while inseting ..

i tried inserting row

like the below

```
$message = new \Messages;
$message->setMessage((string)$vars['message']);
$message->setFrom((int)$vars['from']);
$message->setTo((int)$vars['to']);
$this->em->persist($message);
$this->em->flush();
```

i am getting the following error.

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Messages::setFrom() must be an instance of UserDetails, integer given, called in C:\wamp\xxxxxxxx.php on line 31 and defined in C:\wamp\xxxxxxx\Entities\Messages.php on line 156.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look up or create a `UserDetails` object corresponding to that ID and use that as the argument to `setFrom`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass object instances, just like Dan said. For example:

```
$from = $this->em->find('UserDetails', (int) $vars['from']);
$to   = $this->em->find('UserDetails', (int) $vars['to']);

$message = new \Messages;
$message->setMessage((string)$vars['message']);
$message->setFrom($from);
$message->setTo($to);

$this->em->persist($message);
$this->em->flush();
```

Comment: Also you can use a reference like so: `$from = $this->em->getReference('UserDetails', (int)$vars['from'])`